# mysql_query() not working as expected but phpmyadmin is

Tags: mysql

The following code isn't working as expected using mysql_query() function.

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass') or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('db') or die (mysql_error());

$sql = "SET @orig_lat=33.81978250;SET @orig_lon=-118.10641560; SET @dist =10;SELECT Name, Address, City, State, Zip, 3956 *2 * ASIN( SQRT( POWER( SIN( ( @orig_lat - abs( b.lat ) ) * pi( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) + COS( @orig_lat * pi( ) /180 ) * COS( abs( b.lat ) * pi( ) /180 ) * POWER( SIN( ( @orig_lon - b.lng) * pi( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) ) ) AS distance FROM tblDealer AS b HAVING distance < @dist ORDER BY distance LIMIT 10";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die (mysql_error());

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result) or die (mysql_error());

echo $num_rows;
```

This is working perfect in phpMyAdmin though. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

I am getting the following error when I try to run it:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @orig_lon=-118.10641560; SET @dist =10;SELECT Name, Address, City, State, Zi' at line 1
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [PHP Docs on mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (**multiple queries are not supported**) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

How to overcome this? Use the [**mysqli** extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: It isn't working as well. I used mysqli but it's giving the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/abc/public_html/test.php on line 43

Comment: The mysqli extension is different from the mysql extension in quite a few ways. Please make sure to correctly fetch the data with the mysqli's API.

Comment: I used this with no luck:     $mysqli->real_query($sql);
 
    $res = $mysqli->use_result();
 
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo " zip = " . $row['zip'] . "\n";
    }

Comment: Would you mind updating your question to incorporate the modified source?